# Manifold of all 2x2 Hermitian Matrices

Tags: matrices, complex-manifolds

Is it true that the manifold of all $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrices is $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's true. Here's a diffeomorphism from $\mathbb R^4$ to the matrix manifold:
$$
(a, b, c, d) \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b + ci \\
b - ci & d
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The inverse map is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p & q \\
\bar{q} & s
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto (p, Re(q), Im(q), s).
$$

Answer (score 1):

To give yourself a $2\times 2$ hermitian matrix amounts to give yourself its two diagonal complex coefficients that are real (by the hermitian property), that is, two real numbers, and one of its off-diagonal coefficient which (by the hermitian property) determines the, which make two more real number. In total, you need four real numbers to parametrize the real vector space of $2\times 2$ hermitian matrices. It is therefore isomorphic (i.e. diffeomorphic) to $\mathbf{R}^4$.

Comment: I think you forgot that the diagonal entries must be their own conjugates, hence must be real. That subtracts two dimensions from your dimension-count.

Comment: Indeed... I really should be hanged for that. Lemme correct.

Comment: Perhaps just an afternoon in the stocks rather than actual hanging. :)

Comment: No  no, hanging. ;-)